# x64 Visual Studio 2008 -- inputting huge array

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

I want to write a console application in Visual Studio 2008 that inputs a 3.5 GB array (file), and just adds one to each element of the array. 
I have it configured for release and x64. I set up a project using the CLR console application project type. I running on Vista and have 8 GB of memory.

When I run the program, it is giving me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'
>   occurred in does_it_work_2.exe
>
> Additional information: External
>   component has thrown an exception.

Have I configured anything wrong, why is it not working?

Comment: Have you tried launching the generated executable directly? Visual studio really run the vshost.exe version of your executable to be able to debug it and may have a bug here that is generating the exception.

Comment: Your first problem is the problem itself.  Really? A 3.5GB array FILE?  Put that in a Database and all your troubles disappear.

Comment: I'm assuming .Net? If so, it's not an issue with your memory; SEHException represents an error from unmanaged code which is not mapped to a .Net exception class. If it was an issue with memory, you would have gotten an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Visual Studio is a 32 bit application ;) Debugger = 32 bit, IIRC, not 64 bit ;)

Comment: I've launched the executable directly, and now it works for a while, then says it has stopped working. I'm not getting the error message anymore, but it's just shutting down after about a minute or so.

Comment: Then start debugging (add error handlers ad see what happens there).

Comment: How do I debug the 64 bit app, given the debugger is 32 bit?

Comment: One look into google let me after 10 seconds to that page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681.aspx